# Refine not able to simplify for PositiveReals

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, refine

If I type in Mathematica

```
Refine[d^2 == a^2, {a ∈ PositiveReals, d ∈ PositiveReals}]
```

I get

```
d^2 == a^2
```

Why don't I get `d == a` instead?

Comment: Use `FullSimplify[d^2 == a^2, {a, d} \[Element] PositiveReals]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon In this case, `Simplify` does not work. Why?

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks that worked :) . I'm still curious why Refine wasn't able to do the job though, I thought this is what it did?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - For whatever reason, `Simplify` and `Refine` "timed out" or "ran out of things to try" before they arrived at the desired expression. `FullSimplify` is more robust. However, I have seen cases where `FullSimplify` gave up but `RootReduce` was able to give the desired result; even though `FullSimplify` uses `RootReduce` when it can identify a reason to try it. In general, a desired result may require trying different approaches or even combinations.